# <p> tag removed not using a filter

Tags: filters, the-content

Very strange WordPress behavior: `<p>` tags are removed when placed inside `<pre>` tags, but not always. for example, this works fine:

```
<pre><p>This is a paragraph</p></pre>
```

But when the `<p>` tag is in its own line, it is removed. for example:

```
<pre>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</pre>
```

is printed as:

```
<pre>
    This is a paragraph
</pre>
```

The context in which this is happening is inside `the_loop()` using `the_content()`.
I am using WordPress 4.1

It's not a plugin issue, I've tried disabling them all.
It's not a theme problem, I tried other themes.
It's not a filter, I tried removing all filters using `remove_filter` and even manually using `unset($GLOBALS['wp_filter'][ 'the_content' ])`

What could be causing it?

Comment: In which context are that happening? For example: the content of single post view printed using `the_content()`. Please, [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/173375/edit) and add this information.

Comment: @cybmeta the question was updated

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem in any way. Disable all plugins, including MU plugins (if any), as you did, use a default them (not sure if you tried with core themes or not) and clean the browser cache (just in case there is some javascript in the editor involved).

Comment: @cybmeta I understand. Ill try to dig into it and see if I can get more information.